# JBoss error: org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread)

Tags: wildfly-9

Am trying to run my JBOSS after Configuring mysql dependencies, but having this errors

```
09:49:00,138 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "TripTicketDS")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/TripTicketDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/TripTicketDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
]}
09:49:00,149 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "TripTicketDS")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/TripTicketDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
    "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/TripTicketDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
    "jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/TripTicketDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
]}
```

My standalone.xml configurations are as follows

```xml
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TripTicketDS" pool-name="TripTicketDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trip_ticket</connection-url>
    <driver>mysql</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>root</user-name>
        <password></password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

my SQL module.xml file looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.sql.mysql"> 
    <resources> 
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"/> 
    </resources> 
    <dependencies> 
        <module name="javax.api"/> 
    </dependencies> 
</module>
```

Comment: Can you post your full `module.xml`? One note is you'll also need a dependency on `javax.transaction.api`.

Comment: here is my module.xml file                                                                                                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.sql.mysql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>

Comment: Hi, I've the same problem now with wildfly 10. Did you find the solution ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the Module itself using the   jboss-cli.sh command rather than manually writing the module.xml file. This is because when we use some text editors, they might append some hidden chars to our files. (Specially when we do a copy & paste in such editors)

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /]  module add --name=com.mysql.driver  --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api --resources=/PATH/TO/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar  

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] :reload  
{  
    "outcome" => "success",  
    "result" => undefined  
}
```

After running above command you should see the module.xml generated in the following location:  "wildfly-version.Final/modules/com/mysql/driver/main/module.xml"

Now create DataSource:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql/:add(driver-module-name=com.mysql.driver,driver-name=mysql,jdbc-compliant=false,driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)  
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're driver name is incorrect. It needs to be the same as your module name which is `com.sql.mysql`.

Instead of editing the XML however I'd suggest using CLI or the web console to add the data source. With CLI you can also add the module.

```
module add --name=com.mysql --resources=~/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api

/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=com.mysql:add(driver-name=com.mysql, driver-module-name=com.mysql, driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource)
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=TripTicketDS:add(driver-name=com.mysql, jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TripTicketDS", enabled=true, connection-url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trip_ticket", user-name=root, password="mypassword")
```

Comment: That's a CLI command so you'd just use `%JBOSS_HOME\bin\jboss-cli.bat`. You just need to replace the resource path.